# c# How to identify the cordinates on two diffrent size rectangle?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, imagemagick.net

I have an image of width "ImageWidth",Height "ImageHeight" and PDF of width "PdfWidth",Height "PdfHeight". Both of them has same content(extact replica) but with diffrent dimensions.

Now I am Marking the location lets say (X, Y) on the image. How can I get the same Location in PDF?

Here is my code but it's not perfect

```
var x = Convert.ToInt32(PdfWidth * (XAxies / ImageWidth));
var y = Convert.ToInt32(PdfHeight - (PdfHeight * (YAxies /ImageHeight)));
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, it's just basic geometry. Also what do you mean by "*it's not perfect*"? Have you tried using the same formula for `y` than for `x` i.e. `PdfHeight * YAxis / ImageHeight`?

Comment: The question isn't scientifically correct because it's incomplete. When I tell you I have an image with width 100 and height 150, what are the dimensions of that image? If you can answer that question, you can read my mind. In your case: maybe the dimensions of the image are expressed in pixels (1 inch = 96 pixels) and the dimensions of the PDF are expressed in user units (1 inch = 72 pixels). See https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-7-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdfhtml/how-do-measurement-systems-html-relate-measurement-system-pdf